# TransactionScope() in Sql Azure

Tags: transactionscope, azure-sql-database

Does Sql Azure support using TransactionScope() when performing inserts? Below is a code snippet of what I am trying to do.

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }))
            {
                using (var db = MyDataContext.GetDataContext()) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MyObject myObject =  new MyObject()
                       {
                         SomeString = "Monday"

                       };
                        db.MyObjects.InsertOnSubmit(myObject);
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                        tx.Complete();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                 }
             }
```

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that it works in the case when the transaction scope is tied to only one connection. Often times because its a best practice to open a connection late and close early. there might be situation where the scope spans two connections. Those scenarios are not supported in sql azure.

An example of where it might not work is; taking yr example; Assuming MyDataContext.GetDataContext() returns a new instance of a connection.

```
   using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                                        new TransactionOptions() 
                                            {  IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted }
                                       ))
   {
       try{ 
           DoSomething(); //a method with using (var db = MyDataContext.GetDataContext())
           DoSomethingElse(); //another method with using (var db = MyDataContext.GetDataContext())
           tx.Complete();
       }
       catch { //Exception handler
       }
   }
```

These links should give you some pointers aswell

- [Transactions in Sql
  Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx)

Comment: First link appears to be dead.

Answer (score 3):

Quick update on distributed transactions with Azure SQL Database: A couple of days ago, we introduced support for distributed transactions in Azure SQL Database. The feature that lights up the capability is called elastic database transactions. It focuses on scenarios using the .NET distributed transaction APIs such as TransactionScope. These APIs start working against Azure SQL Database once you installed the new 4.6.1 release of the .NET framework. You can find more information about how to get started here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview/.

Please give it a try!

Comment: Hi Torsten, does that mean we can use a transaction scope around ef to sql azure and around azure service bus in the same scope?

Comment: @Dewy: Unfortunately, you cannot compose SQL Azure and Azure SB in the same scope.

Comment: @TorstenGrabs Do you know if this limitation is still present?