# Alternative to TransactionScope for Entity Framework when using Sql Azure across multiple connections

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I am using EF to access Sql azure. In one situation I need to make changes to two databases, for which normally I would use TransactionScope and it would escalate to MSDTC. Now MSDTC is not supported in Sql Azure, so I can't use TransactionScope.

Is there another way to do this? (other than doing it without the distributed transaction and having to manually rollback state somehow).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to write your code without using the **TransactionScope** class is to use **SqlTransaction**. The SqlTransaction class doesn’t use the transaction manager, it wraps the commands within a local transaction that is committed when you call the Commit() method.

I would suggest you looking at [Handling Transactions in SQL Azure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx) article.

Comment: I guess that article answers it "This means that SQL Azure doesn’t allow Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) to delegate distributed transaction handling. Because of this you can’t use ADO.NET or MSDTC to commit or rollback a single transaction that spans across multiple SQL Azure databases or a combination of SQL Azure and an on-premise SQL Server."

Answer (score 0):

TransactionScope is now supported for Azure SQL DB. See my answer to the following posting: [TransactionScope() in Sql Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604941/transactionscope-in-sql-azure). This also applies when you are using EF.