# Transactions in NServicebus using Azure Service Bus Transport

Tags: azure, transactions, nservicebus, nservicebus4

I have several message handlers in a particular endpoint that do their work against a SQL Azure database (at the moment still using a local SQL 2012 instance).  I have a command handler that publishes 2 events, call them X and Y.  In the same endpoint I have a subscriber to X and a subscriber to Y.  Both of these subscribers are internally using the same data access component, call that Z.  Dependency injection is configured on a per-call basis, not shared.

Component Z is using Entity Framework 6 under the curtains.  The issue I am having is that just opening the database is throwing a SqlException and complaining about MSDTC escalations.

I have temporarily wrapped the handlers in a TransactionScope.Suppress and that has stopped the error but I believe I'm missing something more fundamental.

Is it a simple matter of configuring the endpoint to be non-transactional?  I would have thought this would just work seeing as I've configured to use Azure Service Bus as the transport mechanism.  If I do this will NServiceBus still retry if an exception is thrown within the message handler? (Up to the SLR limits -- not part of the question, I also understand the idempotency issues).

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as a transport for NServiceBus or just as your data storage?
As for Azure Service Bus transport - NSB will retry on exceptions with FLR (and SLR if configured) as usual.

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue, but I'm struggling to understand your setup (what NServiceBus transport are you using?)

Comment: SQL Server is being used solely for data storage.  I am using Azure Service Bus as the transport.  I have also read that if I made it non-transactional I wouldn't get FLR or SLR retries?  Is that correct.

Answer (score 0):

@Phil,

First, you shouldn't be using MSDTC with SQL Azure - it's not supported. The feature is suggested, but only [under review](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/584699-add-dtc-support-for-sql-azure). DTC is not supported on Azure. Alternatively, you could look into the [following suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164345/alternative-to-transactionscope-for-entity-framework-when-using-sql-azure-across) to use SqlTransaction approach.

Second, transport you're using has nothing to do with your data access. Since you're using Azure Service Bus, it will not be part of your handler code. Making handler a transactional is to force an atomic change or roll-back. Regardless of your handler, will retry. Challenge is that when handler/endpoint is not transactional, and within handler first write to DB succeeded and second failed, first write won't be reverted. As for Azure Service Bus as a transport, it's not transactional in its nature (ie no DTC).

Comment: I'm not trying to use MSDTC by any means, I was just surprised that it was being invoked at all, hence my question.  I've since understood how retries work under Service Bus so hopefully the path is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of NServiceBus.Azure are you on? Do you have a stack trace of the exception? Where does it come from?

We push the sends and publishes out of the scope of the receive transaction scope explicitly to prevent promotion to the DTC, so that the transaction is local to the sql, so I doubt that is what is happening here.

From you description it looks like you are using a different data access instance for each handler (per call container config)  and you have multiple handlers on the same message. If both of these open a new connection to the SQL you would see promotion as well (even if it is the same server)

Could that be it? That it throws on the second open?