# Save to multiple databases in a single transaction in SQL Azure Federation

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I need to save to two different SQL Azure federated databases in a **single transaction** so I could rollback all changes if something fails. Right now, I have two separate code blocks that are transacting independently of each other. I tried using TransactionScope, but apparently SQL Azure does not support it.

```
    using (EVENTContext dc = new EVENTContext(
GetConnectionString(1)))
    {
        string federationCmdText = @"USE FEDERATION [fed] ([dist] = '"+ GetDist(1) +"') WITH FILTERING = OFF, RESET";
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)dc).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
        dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(federationCmdText);
        dc.EVENTS.Add(e);
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }


    using (EVENTContext dc = new EVENTContext(
GetConnectionString(2)))
    {
        string federationCmdText = @"USE FEDERATION [fed] ([dist] = '"+ GetDist(2) +"') WITH FILTERING = OFF, RESET";
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)dc).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
        dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(federationCmdText);
        dc.EVENTS.Add(e2);
        dc.SaveChanges();
    }
```

How can I save to multiple databases in a single transaction? I recently started reading about Unit of Work, but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't; it's not supported. The closest thing you can do is to store the records in a pending state (in a column you add for that purpose), and if both commit, you change the records state to Active (or something along those lines). In other words, it's something you need to manage yourself and treat these operations as long running transactions.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could possibly do that. If both commit, then I need to connect to those two databases again to change the records' state to Active. That would be two separate transactions, and one of them might fail.

Answer (score 0):

OK, answering my own question after having thought about this for a while. Here's what I'll try to do:

1) Generate an Action ID per user action (whatever it is) and write it to a table in the root database

2) Append this Action ID to every row so I can track which rows were added for which action

3) Commit to each database separately

4) Delete the action ID from the root database table

All of these steps would be part of one user action, and if an exception is thrown in one step, the following steps wouldn't be executed.

On the application side, I then check to see if the Action ID of whatever I return from the federated tables appears in the root database table. If so, then there was an error committing changes. If not, it was a successful transaction.

Finally, I can run a worker role that, on a regular basis, grabs an Action ID from the root database table and cleans up any rows that have that Action ID, and after deleting them all, removes the Action ID also.

Answer (score 0):

TransactionScope used to not be supported when connecting to Azure SQL DB. You either had separate contexts commit independently (as in your code sample), or you had to implement your own compensation logic as above. Both is no longer necessary as TransactionScope is now supported by Azure DB. See [TransactionScope() in Sql Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604941/transactionscope-in-sql-azure).